# laravel Auth session expire do some action in to database

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make changes (like change user status to logout) in to database when Auth session expires due to inactivity for some time.

Comment: Please mention your code here

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to encourage people to answer your question.

Comment: i think there is no need for code. i am just asking that in laravel if user is inactive for sometime (lets say its 15 minutes. This is set in config/session.php). Then laravel will automatically logout user. if user is inactive for 15 minutes. I think in this case laravel expires auth session. So i wanna make a entry in user table to change its status to  offline.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
SO is a platform where you can get a good suggestion regarding your problems.  But for that, you need to be more specific about what you are asking?  what have you done so far?  Before asking please see the suggested SO question and take a look at them. Still, you did not find a solution then you can ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want control it after a request (which can be done with middlewares) you should use the [Database Session Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#driver-prerequisites). Change it in `config/session` to `'driver' => 'database'`. Then create the session table with artisan:

```
php artisan session:table

composer dump-autoload

php artisan migrate
```

Now you are able to check for users status on sessions table.